# Zooming in and out background image with CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to do animation with my background image and I manage to do it. But I my animation is not running smoothly. If I reduce the animation from **30s** to **5s** it running smooth but the animation is too fast.

My CSS :

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/3768/sky-sunny-clouds-cloudy.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: 0;
    animation: grow 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes grow {
    0%   { background-size: 100% auto; }
    50% { background-size: 140% auto; }
    100% { background-size: 100% auto; }
}
```

Check the result here https://jsfiddle.net/6q3obw82/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the keyframes for the code with adding more breakpoints

```
@keyframes grow {
    0%   { background-size: 100% auto; }
    25%   { background-size: 150% auto; }
    50%   { background-size: 200% auto; }
    75% { background-size: 150% auto; }
    100% { background-size: 100% auto; }
}
```

Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/xgjmesrr/

Comment: Looked better. Thanks!